# Unresolved external symbol error in exe but not in dll

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I have a library (dll) which exposes a class along with its constructors which are supposed to be used in other modules (exe and dll). I am able to instantiate that class from other library modules but not exe modules. I get the linker error - 'error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol' during linking. I am confused why linking succeeds when used in other library projects and not exe project. Can somebody help me with this?

the following is the class declaration:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) MyException
{
public:
MyException(unsigned int _line, const char *_file, const char *_function, MyExceptionType _type, const wchar_t* _message = 0, ...);
};
```

This is the whole error: 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MyException::MyException(unsigned int,char const *,char const *,enum MyException::MyExceptionType,unsigned short const *,...)" (_*imp*??0MyException@@QAA@IPBD0W4MyExceptionType@0@PBGZZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MyClassUsesMyException::MyClassUsesMyException(class SomeClass *,int)" (??0MyClassUsesMyException@@QAE@PAVSomeClass@@H@Z)

MyClassUsesMyException is being instantiated in 'MyApp.cpp'.

Thanks, Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: `wchar_t` Not Always Native**

After a fairly long exchange of information and getting a little more info from the OP, the problem is essential this:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) MyException
{
public:
    MyException(unsigned int _line, 
        const char *_file, 
        const char *_function, 
        MyExceptionType _type, 
        const wchar_t* _message = 0, // <<== note wchar_t type
        ...);
};
```

Visual C++ can be configured to either treat `wchar_t` as a native type or not. When not treated as a native type, `unsigned short` is the specified macro substitution for `wchar_t`. The linker was complaining about the above function being unresolvable, but what really caught my eye was this at the tail of the undefined symbol:

```
,unsigned short const *,...)
```

Note the `unsigned short`. This hinted to me that the compiler was using non-native `wchar_t` when compiling the EXE. I considered it possible that maybe the DLL was compiled with `wchar_t` configured as native, thereby introducing a different signature and thus not matching up at link time.

If you're surprised this was the problem, imagine how surprised Rakesh and I were =P

---

**Original Answer**

That class should be in a single common header with preprocessor logic to determine proper import/export state of the declaration. Like so:

**MyDLL.h**

```
#ifndef MYDLL_H
#define MYDLL_H

// setup an import/export macro based on whether the 
//  DLL implementing this class is being compiled or
//  a client of the DLL is using it. Only the MyDLL.DLL
//  project should define MYDLL_EXPORTS. What it is 
//  defined as is not relevant. *That* it is defined *is*.

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MYDLL_API MyException
{
    // your class definition here...
};

#endif
```

Then, in your DLL project that implements the exception (and **only** in that project), add MYDLL_EXPORTS to the preprocessor defines list in your project configuration.

Comment: I have done that, and the constructors are visible in DependencyExplorer. Like I said, I can use it in some other dll but not in exe - which doesn't make sense. Any idea about this??

Comment: Can you post the *exact* unresolved external symbol, as well as the dependency walker listed export? ( you can cut/paste from depends.exe, in case you weren't aware. damn handy sometimes). The only other thing I can think of off the top of my head is the EXE's being built with a different memory bit config (64 vs 32), but I seriously doubt you'd miss a mistake like that. There is also the possibility you don't have "Link Project Dependencies" enabled for EXE's, but again, sounds like you know what you're doing and would not likely miss that either.

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig, I do have all the options you mentioned enabled. Looks like there's some problem with the address resolution of the constructor during linking with this project, since that dll works fine with other exe projects.

Comment: @RakeshK Ah.. I thought you mentioned it only worked with other DLL projects, but no EXE projects. If you get the chance, I'd still be interested in seeing the specific symbol the linker is whining about not finding. It may help track this down. You never know =P

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share that code - due to privacy reasons, but here's the whole scenario (hope I'm not confusing you): MyException class is defined in 'lib1.dll' and this is being used in a class 'MyClassUsesMyException' defined in 'lib2.dll' and this is being used in an exe - 'MyApp.exe' - each of these components is a vcproj in itself. I've edited my question with the whole error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just fishing here. Do all three projects (I'm assuming they're in the same solution file) have `wchar_t` to be treated as a native type, because it looks like the EXE does *not*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24685/discussion-between-rakesh-k-and-whozcraig)

Comment: @RakeshK Updated. Challenging hunt on this one. Glad it helped.